# Проблемы со статической компиляцией Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, компиляция, static

Имеется проблема. Я решил сделать статическую компиляцию на Qt 5.15.0 MinGW Windows 10. Решил провести на пустом проекте и получил ошибку о том, что не хватает tiff. Я спрашивал - сказали, что надо подключить tiff.

P.S Я скомпилировал исходники Qt MinGW 810 под статическую сборку (там проблем не было).

Прописываю в .pro файле до .lib и include

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\include"
LIBS += "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib\libtiff.lib"
```

**полный .pro файл проекта:**

```
QT       += core gui widgets

CONFIG += c++11

QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += -static -static-libgcc

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\include"

LIBS += "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib\libtiff.lib"

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui
```

Но всё равно выводит с ошибкой. Как решить этот вопрос?
(Компиляция производится в релизе)

Логи:

```
ld.exe: cannot find -ltiff
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:74: release/Test_Static.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: `LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib\" -ltiff`

Comment: @mkkik все равно не помогает.

Comment: Надо проверить, соответствует ли разрядность библиотеки, она, кстати, сама статическая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла повторная перекомпиляция с параметром -qt-tiff.

`configure -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-tiff -qt-webp -opengl desktop -no-angle -sql-sqlite -openssl -I "C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\include" -L "C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64" -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix C:\Qt\5.15.1\mingw81_64_static`

[Инструкция по статической компиляции MinGW](https://github.com/Sepera-okeq/Qt-Static-MinGW)